# Samsung pay integration

Tags: android, samsung-pay

I want to know, is Samsung pay API available for android ?? how can we integrate it into android? I have tried many times but did not get anything, 
i got links like below : http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Samsung_Pay_SCMP_API/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=ch_Registration.5.1.html

can you guide more for it?

Answer (score 2):

To quote [Samsung Support](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00043951/) on this:

> Samsung Pay is focusing on in-store purchases, and at this time, there is no support for implementing in-app purchasing using Samsung Pay. The Samsung Pay SDK and corresponding API documentation will be made available at developer.samsung.com at a later time. For more information on utilizing Samsung's extensive B2B resources, visit the Samsung Partner Portal.

If you already have an account on Samsung Developer/Partner Portal, I would suggest you sign in and get in contact with a representative from Samsung to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible! But it depends on the country and payment gateway you want to work with:

Access https://pay.samsung.com/partners/ and contact a Samsung Pay Relationship Manager

Here is the portal for developers: https://pay.samsung.com/developers